# Mysql SELECT from list of values

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 tables, "orders" and "genlist". In genlist table some generated info, id|date|order_ids(1,2,3,4...). I need to select all orders from "orders" by orders_ids value list from some date.

`id | date| order_ids
---|------|--------
1  | 00-00| 1,2,3,4
2  | 00-00| 5,6,7,8`

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE id IN (
select order_ids from genlist 
where date ='2016-07-04'
)
```

It,s not working properly, return only first element of list order_ids(1,2,3,4...). Just "1"
How can I write this?

Comment: Your column `order_ids`'s value is '1,2,3,4'? Separated by comma?

Comment: Normalise your design

Comment: Yes, `order_ids` 's value separated by comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem.

```
select * from orders 
where FIND_IN_SET(id, (select group_concat(order_ids) 
from gen_list))
```

It's works well , but It should be mentioned that

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet. The syntax to change the value of group_concat_max_len at runtime is as follows, where val is an unsigned integer:

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
  Select *,b.desc1,b.desc2 from
  (Select * from orders) as a

  left join

  (select order_ids,desc1,desc2 from genlist) as b
  on a.order_ids = b.order_ids
```